# Else condition does not work in powershell with GetHostEntry

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a simple script that resolves ip's to hostnames. I have a file of ip addresses in flows.txt and basically I am resolving those ip's to hostnames. The problem is that if there is an ip that is not resolvable, my script does not say "$ip not found" as I have defined it to. Instead, it just outputs that ip address I had listed in my flows.txt file. What I'd like for it to do is say that that particular ip address is not resolvable or just "$ip N/A" If anyone can find my error, please correct me if possible. Thanks!

```
$flows = Get-Content c:\scripts\flows.txt
$resultlist = @()

foreach ($ip in $flows)
{
     $result = $null
     $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
     $result = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ip)

     If ($Result)
     {
          $resultlist += [string]$Result.HostName
     }

     Else
     {
          $resultlist += "$ip - No HostNameFound"
     }
}

$resultlist | Out-File c:\Scripts\output.txt
```

Comment: Your script works fine for me when I tried it. Maybe if this isn't working you should use a Try/Catch for it.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: Script works fine for me too. If I add a nonexistent IP it reports so quite well.

Comment: It is just strange that I don't get the same output. The only thing that returns is that IP which is ok I guess, it helps me narrow down exactly WHICH IP did not resolve but I would have liked to have been able to customize that part.

Comment: Define "ip that is not resolvable". For example, `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry(1)` returns an object with HostName=0.0.0.1. So your code is working fine. The question is what you want to achieve. If you want to see if IP is pingable - ping it. If you need to check if IP is really valid - convert it to uint32 and check if it belongs to one of the valid ranges.